# dll not in my executable file, working in visual studio but not on execution

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, executable, pop3

I'm new to the community. I have a major problem in one of my project. I'm at school but this is a personal project so teachers won't be of any help.
I work with Visual Studio in C#.

In my project, I get mails from a specific dedicated Gmail account in POP3. I use S22.POP3 because it's a free assembly and works very well with what I'm trying to do.

So here's my problem: When I use the executable I get an error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

The error says that the file or the assembly is missing.

After a lot of searching and trying I still don't know what to do. I looked up the interop thing that is on the propriety of the reference but it doesn't seem to be the way to go. It create some errors where I use the class from the assembly. 
Then I looked up DllImport but I am pretty inexperienced and I don't understand it at all. I tried something like this :

```
[DllImport("S22.Pop3.dll")]
static extern
```

But I don't understand what I'm doing here and it's kind of obvious that it doesn't work. I know that I at least need to put something after `static extern` but I don't know what? Anyway this is maybe not the way to go.

I have also seen some people talking about ILMerge. But same problem here I don't know what I'm doing. From the documentation I've found it's for implementing C++.

Please help me, and if you have time, try to do an executable that is able to get mail. Because in Visual Studio it works fine. Once an executable I get the error.

Comment: you can easily fix this by adding the reference to the project, then click on that particular .dll and change the `CopyLocal=` property from `false to true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `DllImport` as this library is managed code.

Just use Nuget to install it like [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/S22.Pop3/).

And then follow the tutorial from the [project page](https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Pop3).

Here is the first example:

```
using System;
using S22.Pop3;

namespace Test {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            /* connect on port 995 using SSL */
            using (Pop3Client Client = new Pop3Client("pop.gmail.com", 995, true))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("We are connected!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```